# Change default Sendgrid mime settings

Tags: sendgrid

I'm trying to change send grid's default implementation of smtp. It's currently sending the email as utf-8 charset (exactly what I need), but for some reason Content-Transfer-Encoding is set to Quote Printable.

Is there any way to change that to 8bit?

Edit:

Sorry folks, here's the additional info: It's the python library running on google app engine :)

thanks!

Comment: What language, which library, and what does your code look like? We can't help unless we know these things.

Comment: The "defaults" are whatever is specified in the SMTP message, so we need to know what SMTP transport library you are using in order to help you change those headers.

Comment: Great point guys, i've updated the question :)